# Tor and online email provider

Tags: email, tor

I am using Tor network and wondering if there are email providers that I can register and use with Tor.

I want to use it in the browser just like Gmail. But I couldn't register there. Gmail wants me to verify myself via SMS. That isn't an option for me. I didn't find any other provider where I can register when I use Tor. It isn't an option to register on normal browser then use it on Tor (then what's the point?)

Is there an email provider that I can use on Tor without registering to it outside of Tor?

Comment: why isn't it an option to verify? Most mail providers use it to prevent spam accounts

Answer (score 2):

> It isn't an option to register on normal browser then use it on TOR (then whats the point?)

It's not entirely pointless.

- If a mail provider does not require SMS/phone verification, then you can easily sign up anonymously, such as from a library PC or at work/school/university. (Don't leave fingerprints.)
- If SMS verification is needed – buy a prepaid card, verify account, then destroy the card.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bit late but I hope you get it and it is useful to you. I had the same compliant/problem and then the perfect solution was provided by [Tor Mail](http://tormail.org/).

> Tor Mail is a [Tor Hidden Service](https://www.torproject.org/docs/hidden-services.html.en) that allows anyone to send and receive email anonymously.

You register and there is no confirmation. Read the home page for information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yahoo Mail this way. It only has a CAPTCHA for verifying you at registration, so you can register there on TOR too, and you can perfectly use it from TOR.

Note: Yahoo mail doesn't work. It might let you sign up but once it notices the ip address changing, it deletes the account.

Answer (score -1):

hushmail.com appears to work fine over tor, and never requests a SMS code.  Very occasionally I'll get a message like "you are accessing us from a bad IP address", creating a new identity in tor fixes this.

Comment: quote: "Canadian company turned over 12 CDs worth of e-mails from three Hushmail accounts, following a court order obtained through a mutual assistance treaty between the U.S. and Canada." If I recall correctly - I also saw somewhere that there is a link between trapwire surveillance system and the company that developed hushmail.

Comment: @Stann Tor means that they cannot trace emails back to your IP address. As long as you don't blatently state your personal details in an email, such as your address and your phone number, they won't be able to look up your IP address, and pay your house a visit.